# Верно ли расставлены знаки в предложении или тире должны стоять во всех частях, то есть пропущены сказуемые?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, правила

Первый этаж под магазин, второй — жилой. Слева от нас торговый центр, а справа — офисные здания.

Answer (score 3):

> Верно ли расставлены знаки в предложении или тире должны стоять во
> всех частях, то есть пропущены сказуемые?

Здесь все правильно. Дополнительные тире возможны, но совсем не обязательны, лучше обойтись без них.

***Первый этаж под магазин, второй — жилой. Слева от нас торговый центр, а справа — офисные здания***

Но вопрос хороший. Дело в том, что правило об опущенном сказуемом часто трактуют неверно, смешивая две совершенно разных ситуации: реальное отсутствие сказуемого и традиционно опускаемый в русском языке глагол-связку "есть". Так вот, в первом из этих случаев тире рекомендуется, а при соблюдении некоторых условий -- даже предписывается. А вот второй случай сам по себе никак не связан с постановкой тире, его ставят по другим мотивам - для передачи интонации или при повторяемости конструкции.

Вот что у Розенталя по этому поводу.

> 1. Тире ставится при наличии паузы в так называемых эллиптических
>    предложениях (самостоятельно употребляемых предложениях с
>    отсутствующим сказуемым):

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93#pp93

То есть тире ставится только при наличии паузы. А кто ж его знает, есть она у автора или её нет? По мне так пауза тут не нужна в обоих ваших случаях.

И второе возможное основание.

> 2. Тире ставится в неполных предложениях при параллелизме конструкций (предложений или частей предложения):

Там же.

Параллелизм в обоих предложениях можно усмотреть, но очень слабый, грамматика или вообще разная (первое предложение) или осложнена противопоставлением (во втором предложении).
Так что императивных оснований для тире в первых частях предложений, судя по всему, нет. Да и вообще непонятно, зачем они там могли бы стоять. А вот во вторых частях обоих предложений тире, формально тоже необязательные, несут определенную нагрузку, они мотивированы пропуском слова, присутствующего в первой части. Это слово - глагол связка нулевой длины. Такая постановка вопроса может вызвать затруднения (как вообще может присутствовать то, чего нет?), но на самом деле все очень просто проверяется. Чтобы убедиться в том, что такая нулевая связка действительно есть в синтаксисе фразы, обычно достаточно поставить предложение в прошедшее время.

*Первый этаж **был** под магазин, второй — жилой. Слева от нас **был** торговый центр, а справа — офисные здания.*

Здесь видно, что тире во вторых частях заменяет глагол связку (был, были), которые в настоящем времени имеют форму нулевой длины. Этим мотивируются тире во вторых частях и в исходной фразе с настоящим временем глагола.

(+)

*В качестве небольшого эссе -- этакого экскурса в академическую грамматику -- добавлю.*

Строго говоря, даже рассмотренной постановкой фразы в прошедшее время еще не все сложности разобраны. В первом предложении "первый этаж был под магазин" вроде бы не хватает какого-то слова типа "отдан" или "предназначен":

*Первый этаж **(был) отдан** под магазин, второй — жилой*

Оно в общем-то так, здесь можно трактовать как фразу с опущенной именной частью составного именного сказуемого (СИС), но сам по себе этот факт недостаточен для обязательного тире на месте отсутствующего члена. К тому же не очень понятно, реально это просто СИС или особый предикат. Тут много спорного, не претендую на истину. Но это уже сугубо академический вопрос, к вопросу о тире непосредственно не относящийся.